# onclick span -> loading.gif is not showed ajaxStart JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onclick, gif

I am doing a table with spans in css. When a span is clicked, I want to show a loading gif while the script insert some data in the database.

This is the span:

```
<span class="label label-<?=$tag?><?=$selected?" selected":" hidden-print"?> customer-<?=$i?>" onclick="connect('customer-<?=$i?>', '<?=$customer?>', '<?=$tag?>');"><?=$tag?></span><?
```

And this is the script:

```
    <script>
  function connect(customerId, customerValue, tagValue){
    var label = $("span.label-"+tagValue+"."+customerId);
    var connectar = !label.hasClass('selected');
    console.log("haciendo " + connectar + " la conexión entre " + customerValue + " y " + tagValue);
    $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
        $('.loading.gif').show();
        alert('Cargando la etiqueta');
    }).ajaxComplete(function(){
        $('.loading.gif').hide();
        alert('Etiqueta cargada');
    });
    $.getJSON( "/api/connect.php?customerId="+customerValue+"&tagId="+tagValue+"&connect="+connectar, function( data ) {
      console.log('error: ' + data.error);
      if(data.error == "false"){
        if(data.connected == "true"){
          label.addClass("selected");
          label.removeClass("hidden-print");
        }
        if(data.connected == "false"){
          label.removeClass("selected");
          label.addClass("hidden-print");
        }
      }
    });
  }
    </script>
```

My problem is here:

```
<script>
  function connect(customerId, customerValue, tagValue){
    var label = $("span.label-"+tagValue+"."+customerId);
    var connectar = !label.hasClass('selected');
    console.log("haciendo " + connectar + " la conexión entre " + customerValue + " y " + tagValue);
    $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
        $('.loading.gif').show();
        alert('Cargando la etiqueta');
    }).ajaxComplete(function(){
        $('.loading.gif').hide();
        alert('Etiqueta cargada');
    })
</script>
```

The script are not showing 'loading.gif', but show 'alert('Cargando la etiqueta');' and 'alert('Etiqueta cargada');'.

The gif 'loading.gif' is in the same folder. Have I a syntax error? Please, need help.

Updated:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
   $('#loader').show();
}).ajaxComplete(function(){
   $('#loader').hide();
});
```

Comment: is .loading.gif a class on one of your html elements or you are thinking that .loading.gif.show() will show the image itself??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**html**

```
<img src="loading.gif" id="loader" alt="loading"/>
```

**css**

```
#loader { display:none; }
```

**js**

```
$("#loader").show();
```

---

problem is that your code: `$("loading.gif").show()` - will not actually bring the element into the page

---

**Update as the comment questions**

```
 <html>
   <head>
    <title>Showing placement of these parts</title>
     <style>
      #loader { display:none; }
     </style>
   </head>
  <body>
     <img src="loading.gif" id="loader" alt="loading"/>
     <script src="pathto/jquery.js"></script>
     <script>
        $("loader").show();
     </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Just showing the order in the HTML document

---

**Update in context**

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
        $('loader').show();
        alert('Cargando la etiqueta');
    }).ajaxComplete(function(){
        $('loader').hide();
        alert('Etiqueta cargada');
    });
});
```

Comment: For what is "css #loader { display:none; }"?

Comment: once you add the image to the page in your html, you will want to hide it from view until you '.show()' it. - ( .show() creates css of display:block and .hide() creates css of display:none )

Comment: Ok i added ccs, but it still no works. Where have i to put the html code?

Comment: somewhere between the <body></body> tags of your html and above the javascript code.

Comment: Hey, excuse me. I do what you said me and It works perfect! But when I click span the loading.gif never stops. It works perfectly in my cellphone, the problem is on pc.

Comment: when you want the loading gif to stop - you can set $("loader").hide();

Comment: I did it and look what is happenning http://img837.imageshack.us/img837/1453/2t82.png. I need the gif only when i click an specific span. Help me i am very close to finish my page.

Comment: Did you add '$('loader').show();' outside of your 'ajaxStart' function ? if so remove it, was only for demo purposes

Comment: I updated the question. Currently I have the script so.

Answer (score 0):

$('.loading.gif').show() will not load the image and show it. best way is to have some html

```
<img class="loader" src="loader.gif"/>
```

and have js as

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $('.loader').show();
})
```

Comment: Where i have to put <img class="loader" src="loader.gif"/> ?

Comment: @nandophillips you can put it in HTML file and where you want your loader to be visible